# What makes a robust RS232 serial communication scheme on an embedded device?

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, timing

So I'm starting to have a reoccurring problem with writing serial communication schemes, and it seems to be due to timing.  My embedded platform is the Rabbit Semiconductor BL2600, and in this case, it is talking to a device on RS232.  It sends out a command to the device, and the device sends a reply back to the BL2600, which is then processed.

My issue is though, that when I send out the command, and then wait for a response, I don't get one.  However if I set a breakpoint at the right spots, and single step through the code, I often do get the response.  I have placed my computer in between the BL2600 and the device to listen in to the RS232 stream (after seeing the initial problem), and the reply is being sent no matter if I breakpoint or not, but the BL2600 only sees it in its buffers if I stop just before the part where I parse the code and try to find its start bit.  If I breakpoint when its just reading the the whole string afterwards, it won't find it.

So, that just sounds like I'm not waiting enough, so now just to be ridiculous, I have set the timeouts for checking the buffer up to 1 second (and with a baud rate of 38400, it had better show up in that window), and yet I STILL get nothing unless I breakpoint and single-step.

Below is the significant part of my code:

```
    //clear the buffers
 serCwrFlush();
 while(serCwrUsed())
 {
  ;
 }
 startwait = MS_TIMER;
 while((serCrdUsed() > 1) && (device_timeout_check < 1000))
 {
  if (MS_TIMER < startwait)
  {                                    // fix the rollover
   device_timeout_check = MS_TIMER + (ULONG_MAX - startwait);  
  }

  else
  {                                   //set it like normal
   device_timeout_check = MS_TIMER - startwait;     
  }

  serCrdFlush();
 }
 serCputs("mpcal=d\r");     //This is what requests the response from the device
 while(serCwrUsed())
 {
  ;
 }
 startwait = MS_TIMER;
 while((serCrdUsed() < 11) && (device_timeout_check < 1000))
 {
  if (MS_TIMER < startwait)
  {                        // fix the rollover
   device_timeout_check = MS_TIMER + (ULONG_MAX - startwait);  
  }
  else
  {                       //set it like normal
   device_timeout_check = MS_TIMER - startwait;     
  }
 }
 //grab it
 temp=serCpeek();
 i=0;
        //It expects a response like "H0V0M00.0 /r"
        //So I am looking for the first character.
 while((temp != 'H' ) && (i<100))
 {
  serCgetc();     //breakpoint works here
  temp=serCpeek();
  i++;
 }
 c=serCread(comp_cal_string,20, 20);   //breakpoint doesn't work here
```

I have a feeling that I am re-inventing the wheel, and that somebody has probably done this before me, at least on another platform, so that it is delayed long enough for the data to be received, but fast enough that it actually catches the data.

Comment: Have you looked at the signal with an oscilloscope? You can't do stuff like this without a proper scope. If you are having glitches etc on the UART lines, you may be getting false inputs. Always start by verifying that the actual signal looks ok before digging down in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you're not using interrupt-driven RS-232 communications?  Usually what happens is an interrupt is triggered on an edge transition from the RS-232 circuitry, and you set up an interrupt service routine (ISR) to handle it - that way, you ALWAYS get to process the information, because the interrupt is hardware-driven.  The pulse from the RS-232 circuitry *may* be short enough that your polling loop (above) is just not seeing it.

If your BL2600 is the same device as described here:

http://ftp1.digi.com/support/documentation/019-0113_N.pdf

That manual lists interrupt vectors for all four serial ports on the device - see setVectIntern on page 476.

Also, older RS-232 circuitry only supported internal buffers of 16 bytes.  If you're looking to crank up the baud rate, you may need to use the DMA features that seem to be present on the BL2600.  (The DMA features should automate the transfer of large blocks of data from memory to serial port and vice versa.)

Answer (score 2):

The key to robustness is error handling.

There are two loops that can time out, but neither does anything different when a timeout occurs. There are calls to functions whose return values are not checked for errors. Code that doesn't handle errors is never robust.

The timeout loops are broken in three ways that could affect your reading:

- The value of `device_timeout_check` is tested before its value is set inside the loop.
- `MS_TIMER` is volatile and can change between the time it is tested and used to calculate `device_timeout_check`.
- Nothing is done when a timeout occurs.

To fix these problems, first change the declaration of startwait to avoid rollover problems:
`unsigned long startwait;`. Then implement the timeout loops like this:

```
startwait = MS_TIMER;
do {
  device_timeout_check = (MS_TIMER - startwait >= 1000);
} while((serCrdUsed() > 1) && !device_timeout_check);

if (device_timeout_check) {
   /* Handle the timeout error here */
}
```

This will solve the problem if `device_timeout_check` is greater than 999 when your code is reached.

There is another problem with the loop trying to detect the first 'H' character. The code prior to it only ensures that there are 11 characters available. The detection loop runs 100 times, but allows no extra time for characters to be received. If there are already 11 or more non-'H' characters in the buffer, they will be consumed immediately and there will be waiting for the 'H'.

It would be better to wait for the 'H' first and then wait for the eleven characters. This will solve the problem if the desired input is preceded by undesired input.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dingo has the answer correct with his first finding.  device_timeout_check is not initialized, at least in the code presented here.  If it's not initialized, it's just whatever garbage was left on the call stack, so it could be easily over 1000.  In that case, the while loops immediately fall through silently (tsk tsk), and the while loop waiting for 'H' will rapidly run through 100 iterations pulling nothing (most likely) from the serial port.

BTW, why 100?  Once you empty the buffer, those extra reads are most likely going to occur so fast that they are not going to find anything new.

This also perfectly explains the behavior with the debugger.  Your delay loops were never really delaying anything, and when you put a breakpoint at serCgetc(), you were allowing for the serial port to catch up with the program.

An easy way to see if this is really the case is to setup some kind of external notification before you attempt to read the data from the serial port.  Either blink an LED or send a "message received" packet across the serial port.  Then with a cheap O-scope you should easily see the "message received" packet (or LED blink) be transmitted before the reception of the data.

Those peek and read functions don't return error status since they return data, but they could easily be placed in wrappers that at least checked for parity errors or bytes in the FIFO, and returned data in a pointer instead so status could be returned.  Something like this

```
STATUS myCpeek( unsigned char *data)
{
  if ( 0 == serCrdUsed() )
    return ERROR_NO_DATA;
  *data = serCpeek();
  if ( serCParityError() )  //Just guessing at a function name here
  {
    return ERROR_PARITY_BAD;
  }
  return OK;
}
```

or something similar.